# How to interpret cProfile results of PuLP

Tags: python, profiling, pulp, cprofile

I fear I am a bit in over my head. I have profiled a Mixed Integer Problem (MIP) with `cProfile` and `gprof2dot`. The MIP is implemented via the `pulp` library. The MIP problem is solvable, which I tested on smaller problems. I profiled the MIP on a larger problem, for which it could not find a solution.

In the following picture of the cProfile output, it can be seen that 88.83% of the time the file is active in the function `WaitForSingleObject`. I am not familiar enough with the `pulp` source code to know what times are appropriate for this part of `ActualSolve`. Intuitively, I expected that most time needs to be spend in the `ActualSolve`. However, for me it seems like within this function, the most time is spent waiting. Is it possible to reduce this waiting time?

Thanks in advance and kind regards.
[image: Profile of MIP]

Comment: In fact the waiting time is pulp waiting for the solver (CPLEX in this case) to finish solving the problem. If you want to interrupt the solving after a fixed time you can pass a `timeLimit` parameter to the solver.

Comment: Thank you pchtsp, that makes a lot of sense!